# Is $apptype a Best Practice Comment?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I just started using FPC to practice more my old knowledge of Pascal, but now for Linux, then I started seeing much this comment after the 'program' declaration:

```
{$apptype console}
```

But is this a best practice comment or a type of declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{$ ...}` are not just comments but they are compiler directives.

Here is a list of [compiler directives.](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progch1.html)

Specifically, `{$apptype console}` tells the compiler to make a console instead of a gui application.

Comment: {$apptype console} can also be useful to add a console in a GUI application. For example for DUnit / FPCUnit tests if you need some log messages to be displayed while the tests are running.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but contrary to Delphi, in FPC console is default.  Delphi has GUI default (*)

Because the defaults vary between Delphi and FPC, it is a reasonable practice to add it, if there is a chance the code must run under Delphi.

(*) strictly speaking not, since the console app flag can also be set using the cmdline. But while thus not 100% mandatory, it is smart to add it in 99.9% of the cases in Delphi.